# Start Mysql/Mariadb in Fedora failed

Tags: fedora, mysql, mariadb

failed to start mysql in Fedora 17. I am using `root` account to run the below commands and selinux is disabled.

```
service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  mysqld.service
Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

systemctl status mariadb.service
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2014-09-23 11:29:32 SGT; 10s ago
  Process: 4251 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4250 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 4222 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4250 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: 140923 11:29:32 mysqld_safe WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error='/var/...er.pid'
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 138: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 182: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: 140923 11:29:32 mysqld_safe WSREP: Failed to recover position:
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: ''
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 138: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Sat 2014-04-26 15:18:22 SGT, end at Tue 2014-09-23 11:29:34 SGT. --
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 138: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 182: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: 140923 11:29:32 mysqld_safe WSREP: Failed to recover position:
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: ''
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 138: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Sep 23 11:29:34 acer-4930g PackageKit[4204]: daemon quit

getenforce 
Permissive
```

Then I changed ownership of the mariadb log file from `root` to `mysql` but still failed:

```
[root@acer-4930g ~]# ls -ld /var/log/mariadb/
drwxr-x---. 2 mysql mysql 4096 Sep 23 11:02 /var/log/mariadb/
[root@acer-4930g ~]# ls -l /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log 
-rw-rw----. 1 root root 554 Sep 23 11:02 /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
[root@acer-4930g ~]# chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mariadb -chR
[root@acer-4930g ~]# systemctl restart mariadb.service 
Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

[root@acer-4930g ~]# systemctl status mariadb.service 
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2014-09-23 14:58:09 SGT; 3min 4s ago
  Process: 6890 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6889 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6861 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6889 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:08 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade ...ate it.
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:08 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine...-tables
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:08 [ERROR] Aborting
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:08  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:09  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1597945
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:09 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete'
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Permissions?

You're showing the command `service mysqld start` but are you prefixing that with a `sudo`? I suspect you do not have permissions to start this service based on the fact that you're getting these "permission denied messages" in the output you've included in your Q.

```
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 138: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 182: /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log: Permission denied
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: 140923 11:29:32 mysqld_safe WSREP: Failed to recover position:
Sep 23 11:29:32 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[4250]: ''
```

If you are in fact using `sudo` then I'd move my attention to the directory & files mentioned in the logs messages above. Focus on this directory/file:

```
$ ls -ld /var/log/mariadb
$ ls -l /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
```

I found these commands in this AskFedora Q&A titled: [mariadb service don't start: permission denied](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/40736/mariadb-service-dont-start-permission-denied/), which should fix your issue:

```
$ sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mariadb -chR
```

followed by:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service && \
    sudo systemctl status mariadb.service
```

It appears that the MariaDB log files do not allow the user, `mysql` access to them, the above commands will fix this problem.

#### DB corrupt?

If you still continue to have problems and are confronted with errors such as:

```
Sep 23 14:58:09 acer-4930g mysqld_safe[6889]: 140923 14:58:08 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade ...ate it.
```

You can also confirm now that the permissions problem above has been resolved, in the MariaDB log file for messages like so:

```
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Either message is basically telling you that there were issues in upgrading your MySQL DB to a Maria DB one. If it's a DB with nothing you care about in it, you can simply move it or remove it. This will require that you first remove the MariaDB package, and then re-install it.

#### Example

```
$ sudo yum remove mariadb-server

### To remove
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/mysql

### To move
$ sudo mv /usr/lib/mysql /usr/lib/mysql.orig

$ sudo yum install mariadb-server
```

**NOTE:** Source for the above tip: [Trouble starting mariadb service](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/42222/trouble-starting-mariadb-service/).

One thing with the above tip that I cannot confirm, is whether the directory to move/remove is `/usr/lib/mysql`. or `/var/lib/mysql`. I'm not sure if that' a typo in that tip or not. So I would do the above with `/usr/lib/mysql` first and if it doesn't work then repeat the steps but with `/var/lib/mysql`. I would use the remove method first, if things work OK, then come back and remove the corrupted directory.

**NOTE:** `/var/lib/mysql` is where the DB files live, the `/usr/lib/mysql` directory is where the various plugins live.

Comment: changed ownership of log directory and file but still cannot start

Comment: @Xianlin - same issue as yourself: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160277. I'd hold off in doing what's suggested here unless you're feeling desperate, these options seem a little aggressive in deleting the DB files and such.

Comment: @Xianlin - also is there more to what you're doing here then you mentioned? Was there an upgrade done from MySQL to MariaDB here and there was a pre-existing DB on the system?

Comment: @Xianlin - see updates.

Comment: my problem was solved by chown /var/lib/mysql to mysql:mysql thanks!